# Escribir a un archivo mapeado en memoria (usando mmap)

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de aprender a usar mmap; he conseguido leer de un fichero mapeado en memoria, sin embargo al intentar escribir obtengo constantemente un "segmentation fault". El código (para escribir) que me falla es el siguiente:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <sys/mman.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 int main()
 {
     FILE* punte;
     char* prueba;

     punte=fopen("prueba.txt","w");

     prueba=(char*)mmap(NULL,sizeof(char)*1,PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fileno(punte),0);

     prueba[0]='A';

     munmap(prueba,sizeof(char)*1);
     fclose(punte);

     return 0;
 }
```

Es una tontería de código que solo pinta la letra 'A' en el archivo de texto, pero soy incapaz de hacerlo funcionar.

Solución (de @eferion):

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <sys/mman.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>

 int main()
 {
     int file;
     char* prueba;

     file=open("prueba.txt", O_RDWR);    //<-- esto  SI funciona
     //file=open("prueba.txt", O_WRONLY); //<-- Pero esto no!

     lseek(file, 9, SEEK_SET);

     write(file, "", 1);

     prueba=(char*)mmap(NULL,sizeof(char)*10,PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,file,0);

     prueba[0]='A';

     munmap(prueba,sizeof(char)*10);

     close(file);

     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en el *stream* del archivo:

```
punte=fopen("prueba.txt","w");
```

Aquí se abre un archivo y tu recibes un puntero al *stream* del mismo... es decir, tu no escribes físicamente en el fichero sino en una región de memoria asociada al mismo... ¿Que tamaño tiene esa región de memoria? Dado que el fichero no tiene contenido, su tamaño actual es 0.

```
prueba=(char*)mmap(NULL,sizeof(char)*1,PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fileno(punte),0);
```

... despues configuras `mmap`...

```
prueba[0]='A';
```

... y el programa expota en esta última línea de código. ¿La razón? El tamaño del *stream* del fichero sigue siendo 0, luego la posición `0` no pertenece al *stream*.

La solución puede ser tan "*sencilla*" como forzar una redimensión del *stream*. Para ello hay que ejecutar tres pasos:

**cambiar fopen por open**

`mmap` necesita un identificador en vez de un puntero de tipo `FILE`. Este identificador lo proporciona, en este caso, la función `open`. Por otro lado, mientras que `fopen` te ofrece un puntero a un buffer intermedio, `open` permite trabajar directamente con el fichero... y con `mmap` pretendes mapear la memoria del fichero... no su buffer intermedio sobre el cual no tienes control alguno. Un ejemplo:

```
int punte = open("prueba.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
```

¿Y no funcionaría con `O_WRONLY`?

```
int punte = open("prueba.txt", O_WRONLY);
```

No. y el motivo es que `O_WRONLY` solo proporciona privilegios de escritura (sin privilegios de lectura) y para este caso no puedes manejar memoria sobre la que no tengas privilegios de lectura.

**Posicionar el cursor del fichero**

De esta forma se redimensionará el fichero. Esta operación es necesaria para garantizar que la memoria asociada al fichero nos permite trabajar de forma segura con `mmap` sin escribir fuera de la misma:

```
size_t size = 10; // pongamos de momento un tamaño razonable

if (lseek(punte, size-1, SEEK_SET) == -1)
{
  close(punte);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

**Escribir algo en el fichero**

No estoy seguro de si este paso es necesario, ya que no puedo probar el código.

En este caso vamos a guardar una cadena vacía, es decir, al fichero únicamente viajará el `\0`. Nota que este caracter se almacenará después de los 10 caracteres que hemos reservado en el paso anterior.

```
if (write(punte, "", 1) == -1)
{
    close(punte);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Y ya está. Ahora el *stream* tiene espacio para que puedas escribir en el sin escribir fuera de la memoria asociada al mismo.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar :-(    (he editado la pregunta para incluir tu modificación, por si acaso la he implementado mal)

Comment: @Guillermo.D.S. ¿Por qué usas `fileno` en las funciones que te he puesto? Eso no está en mi respuesta

Comment: porque esas funciones piden un número de descriptor de archivo, no la dirección del stream. Si lo ejecuto sin      fileno      me da warning (y sigue siendo "segmentation fault").

Comment: Vale, perdona, se me pasó... prueba a abrir el fichero con `open`. Esa función te devuelve un descriptor. Si con eso no funciona no puedo ayudarte mucho más porque no tengo un linux sobre el que hacer pruebas

Comment: ¡Sí! Eso funciona; aún así tengo dos preguntas: la primera está en el código (he vuelto a editarlo): ¿por qué si abro el fichero con la etiqueta O_WRONLY no funciona (segmentation fault)? Y segunda: ¿eing? ¿Por qué puede ser que no funcione con fopen? Gracias @eferion

Comment: @Guillermo.D.S. Porque no puedes tener una memoria de solo escritura. SIEMPRE tienes que tener, al menos, privilegios de lectura en la memoria. En el segundo caso es que open y fopen funcionan de forma diferente. Por ejemplo, fopen utiliza un buffer intermedio mientras que con open atacas directamente la memoria del fichero (fopen suele tener, por este motivo, mejores tiempos de respuesta)